# When to use which OIDC/OAuth flow?

Tags: oauth, openid-connect

I'm immensly confused as to which OAUTH/OIDC flow to use when...

I've put together the following list to work through the options, and would appreciate someone correcting me if I'm getting it wrong. Thank you.

What I think I've understood so far is the following use cases:

- A server-generated views web app (eg: ASP.NET or ASP.MVC based) that is refreshing on every request, and does not use AJAX to access authenticated APIs: use authorization code grant type flow.
- A server-generated views web app (eg: ASP.MVC based) that is refreshing often, but does use AJAX to access authenticated APIs, and the server does not access 3rd parties APIs either as itself (the app) or on behalf of the user: use authorisation code grant type flow
  server set session cookie to access APIs.
- A server-generated views web app (eg: ASP.MVC based) that is refreshing often, but does use AJAX to access authenticated APIs, and the server does access 3rd parties APIs as itself (the app): use authorisation code grant type flow
  server set session cookie to access APIs + use client credential grant type flow.
- A client-side generated views web app (SPA), where the client invokes authenticated API endpoints on its source server, and the server does not invoke 3rd parties services as either itself (the app) or as the user: use implicit grant type flow, caching the authentication token in the user agent's sessionstorage, and passing the authentication_token* back on every request as a Bearer Token.
- A client-side web app (SPA), where the client invokes authenticated API endpoints on its source server, and the server does invoke 3rd parties services as itself (the app): use implicit grant type flow, caching the authentication token in the user agent's sessionstorage, and passing the authentication_token back on every request as a Bearer Token, and use the client credential grant type flow*.
- **This probably is the most uncertain one:** A client-side web app (SPA), where the client invokes authenticated API endpoints on its source server, and the server does invoke 3rd parties services as the the user: use implicit grant type flow, caching the authentication token in the user agent's sessionstorage, and passing the authentication_token back on every request as a Bearer Token, which the server can pass on to the 3rd party services (CHECK) to authenticate the user with. As the token is only encoded and signed, not encrypted, the token's claims can be read. Note: that may contain claims not intended for the 3rd party service.
- Alternatively the flow might be:
  The UI could precheck that the User is allowed to access the 3rd party service (eg: Order Flowers) and gray out the functionality to use the server api that will invoke the 3rd party service till the user has collected and stored a second authorisation token (but then how would the user agent pass that token back, if the call to the API was already using the authorisation header for its own bearer token?)